# Le mot nimbus est-il un suffixe ?

Tags: latin

Le mot *nimbus* (du latin nimbus, nuage de pluie) peut se retrouver dans le nom de nuage *Cumulonimbus*, il serait donc considéré comme un suffixe.

Cependant, on remarque que dans le nom de nuage *Nimbostratus* on peut retrouver *Nimb-ostrat-us*.

Est ce que dans cette situation nous avons séparé *nimbus* en un préfixe (*Nimb*) et un suffixe (*us*) ? Nimbus pourrait donc être utilisé comme un suffixe en étant lui même composé d'un préfixe et d'un suffixe ? Ou alors je me trompe et il n'y a pas de lien entre Nimbostratus et Nimbus ?

Comment: 'préfix ou suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, ***nimbus*** n'est pas vraiment un suffixe ou un préfixe. Comme tu l'as dit dans ta question, c'est simplement un substantif qui signifie nuage. On le retrouve dans des combinaisons de mots où il est juxtaposé avec d'autres :

> cumulonimbus : cumulus + nimbus

> nimbostratus : nimbus + stratus

ou les plus rares :

> altocumulonimbus : préfixe alto (haut) + cumulus + nimbus

> pyrocumulonimbus : préfixe pyro (chaud) + cumulus + nimbus

de la même façon :

> stratocumulus : stratus + cumulus

Dans tous ces mots, la terminaison ***-us*** est simplement la marque du nominatif en latin et ***-o*** celle du datif.

Answer (score 0):

Ce mot qui vient tout droit du latin via l'emprunt qu'un scientifique anglais a fait au latin pour construire la nouvelle forme « nimbostratus », ne contribue aux termes dans lesquels on le trouve qu'en tant que mot et son utilisation résulte donc souvent en mots composés.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nimbus))     NIMBUS, subst. masc.
> MÉTÉOR., vx. Gros nuage bas et gris, sans forme nette, porteur de pluie ou de neige.
> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nimbostratus))  **Étymol. et Hist.** 1804 (Sur les modifications des Nuages [trad. de l'angl., v. infra) ds Bibl. britannique, Sc. et Arts, t.27, p.203). Empr., par L. Howard dans sa nomenclature des nuages établie en 1803, au lat. nimbus «nuage de pluie», v. nimbe (On the modifications of Clouds, [Réimpr. Berlin, 1894], p.6).

Voilà une assertion explicite qui confirme la nature morphologique de cet [élément formant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9l%C3%A9ment_formant).

> ([Wiktionnnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cumulonimbus))  **cumulonimbus** Étymologie Mot composé de cumulus et de nimbus.

Attention, il peut ne pas en être de même pour d'autres éléments formants dans le domaine de la nomenclature météorologique : par example « strato » est un préfixe.

Comme « nimbostratus » vient de l'anglais, il faut se rapporter à la langue anglaise, il me semble.

> ([etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nimbostratus)) "thick, low, dark cloud from which rain or snow falls," 1932 (earlier use from late 19c. refers to different cloud types), from Modern Latin nimbus "cloud" (see nimbus) + connecting element -o- + stratus (see stratus). Nimbus as "a rain cloud" is attested from 1803.

On parle donc de « stratus » en tant que mot. Selon le point de vue français on pourrait parler de suffixe, mais il semble plus logique de parler de mot entrant dans une composition. (à ne pas confondre avec « strato- » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/strato-) : élément formant).

La transformation de « us » en o n'est qu'une modification mineure, un moyen de rendre le composé euphonique, il me semble.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stratus)) REM.
> -stratus, élém. de compos.V. cirro-stratus (comp. 2 s.v. cirrus), cumulo-stratus (rem. b s.v. cumulus1), nimbo-stratus (rem. 2 s.v. nimbus).
> **Étymol. et Hist.** 1830 (M. C. Bailly de Merlieux, Résumé compl. de météor., p. 119). Mot lat. stratus « étendu » (v. strate), part. passé de sternere « étendre »; déjà en angl. en 1803, v. NED.